# NameError exceptions on finding matching Controller action Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

I'm reading active_support documentation and it says that whenever there's a controller action called, rails searches for corresponding helper class. If there's no such class, an exception is thrown, caught and possibly rethrown.

I'm curious how (in)efficient is this and should I just have empty helper classes for the sake of not throwing exceptions in the background of my code?

I'm not trying to do any kind of premature optimization, I'm just looking into internals of rails and was curious as to why would they make it so that it always throws exception when there's no helper defined.

Here's the related documentation:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-nameerror

Any insights and more details would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you experiencing a problem, or are you trying to fix a problem you're not experiencing yet?

Comment: Great question. I'm just curious about rails internals, not actually trying to fix anything. EDIT: added explanation behind why I posted the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer from a place of "wishful thinking", not from any particular knowledge about Rails internal code. I know (and love) that Rails was built with the busy developer in mind: it was designed by someone who [hates repeating himself](http://fourhourworkweek.com/2014/08/25/the-art-of-strategic-laziness/), with an ethos of DRY code and sensible defaults in mind.

So given that, it sounds like a horrible idea to worry about setting up empty helper classes just for the sake of making the Rails startup code more efficient. That's very opposite to the intentions that Rails was built on, and I think you can count on the community holding to those intentions going forward.